# PHP Apache ImageMagick extension won't load

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick

I am runnning 64-bit Windows 7 with Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4.4 VC9. I have downloaded and installed ImageMagick 6.6.4 and successfully tested it from the command prompt. I have restarted my computer. I have tried many different extension files and keep getting the following error in my Apache logs.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\PHP\\ext\\php_imagick_ts.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

I have my `extension_dir` set to `C:\PHP\ext`. And I of course have added the line `extension=php_imagick_ts.dll` modified according to which file I am trying.

Comment: How did you download and install? Looks like it's missing one or more dependencies.

Comment: I use the windows binary from the website. ImageMagick-6.6.4-0-Q16-windows-dll.exe . I tried many versions and this is the first one that worked after install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Imagick working on Win7 x64 with PHP 5.4 (only tested commandline, but Apache should work) using the beta libraries as compiled and hosted here: http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/

I installed ImageMagick via the ImageMagick-6.8.0-7-Q16-windows-dll.exe file on the [ImageMagick downloads page](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).

```
C:\>php -v
PHP 5.4.0 (cli) (built: Feb 29 2012 19:24:02)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

C:\>php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
imagick
...
```

I haven't actually tested *using* this extension yet, but I'm fairly confident that this will work, given that all of the other .dlls I tried resulted in php.exe crashing when I tried simply running `php -v`!

Comment: I am also able to installed it from ...dll.exe without any problem. I can run it in command line and can do all available actions one can do through commandline. I am trying to run it in Apache but it wont load the extension. I am trying it in wamp server.

Comment: @ArvindK. : You may find that Apache and command-line PHP have different php.ini files, so you will need to put the required `extension=php_imagick_ts.dll` (or whatever it is) line in both files for ImageMagick to be available in Apache as well as CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that ended up working for me was to load php 5.3. Began working immediately.